# change size for select by javaScript in robot +python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
e = self._current_browser().find_element_by_xpath("//label[text()='" + label + "']/../..//select")
print "e:", e
self.execute_javascript("return arguments[0].size", e)
self.capture_page_screenshot("C:/base.png")
self.execute_javascript("arguments[0].size=1", e)
```

> FAIL : TypeError: sequence item 1: expected string, WebElement found

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Where do you get the error? what is `label`?

Comment: @Guy     label is argument that come in from outside,To find select element

Comment: Again, where do you get the error? and it doesn't matter where `label` comes from, it matter what is it (int, string, webelement...).

Comment: @Guy OK this error is get in ride-IPython. Now，I've solved it
can do this way such as
self._current_browser().execute_script("arguments[0].size=1", e)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `label` is a WebElement that you have found using a previous selenium find method. But in the context of `find_element_by_xpath("//label[text()='" + label + "']/../..//select")` it must be a string. You need to ask for the `text()` part of `label` and then use the `extract` method to get the string you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
e = self.get_element_xpath("//*[contains(text(), '" + label + "')]//select")
self._current_browser().execute_script((arguments[0]).size=arguments[0].length", e)
```